# Xcode analyze and whether I should release retained IBOutlet?

Tags: objective-c

Xcode Analyze complained that I incorrectly decremented reference count for username.

Here is the declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *username;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *password;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *login;
```

Here is the dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.username release];
    [self.password release];
    [self.login release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally you don't do

```
[self.username release];
```

but either

```
self.username = nil;
```

or

```
[username release];
```

I'm not sure if that would cause it to complain like that though, esp since you are doing it for all your properties.

Comment: @logancautrell: it may be that the OP has a project with ARC. In that case you would be warned for incorrectly decrementing the reference count on an object with a local reference count of only 1 (because `release` code for the owning reference will be automatically inserted at compile time, so you'll end up with 2 releases in code).

Answer (score 0):

for your viewControllers you should make sure that you set your IBOutlet's to nil in viewDidUnload because the viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload methods may be called multiple times during the life cycle of the view controller.

you should probably use this:

```
-(void)viewDidUnload{
    self.username=nil;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [username release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```